# Centos running very slow in Virtualbox

Tags: performance, virtual-machine, virtualbox, cpu-usage

I am running Centos 7 in Virtualbox 4.3.14.  The VM is configured with

- 2 CPUs
- 4 GB RAM
- 3.10.0-123.4.4.el7.x86_64 kernel

The host machine is running

- Windows 7 Pro SP1 64-bit
- Intel i7-4790 CPU, Hyper-Threading enabled
- 16 GB RAM

Yet, when I start up this VM, it bring my entire system almost to a halt, including my host OS.  In Process Explorer of System Internal, I can see all my cores are maxed out by VirtualBox.  On my VM using top, the load average is about 2 when the system "idles".

- I have tried the dummy VM trick as per http://tech.shantanugoel.com/2009/07/07/virtualbox-high-cpu-usage-problem-solved.html
- I have tried the divider trick as per https://community.oracle.com/message/9307831
- I have tried disabling
  "Nested-Paging" as per ... (cannot add more links with my rep)

Previously I used to run a similar configuration using only a laptop with 6 GB of RAM without any problems.

What else can I try to make this VM usable?

Comment: Could you show what you see when you run top on your guest?

Comment: I cannot. I need more "rep".On the i7 server get a load average of 15.37 (top processes are java processes that take 12.5% - 40.6% each). I copied the same VM to an i5 laptop with only 8 GB RAM and got a load average of 2.28 (top processes are the same java processes that take 17.3% - 17.6% each).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_average#Unix-style_load_calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the physical host machine's CPU fan was never plugged in and because the CPU was overheating, the system slowed down to protect itself.